# Automating Opsworks: How do you execute recipes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation

I'm using the awscli to try to automate a deployment process (upload cookbook changes to s3, click stuff to update cookbooks, click stuff to run a recipie, type in the name of the recipe i want to execute).

I'm really close, but I can't find anything about how to actually execute a given recipe in opsworks through the awscli.  I figure it must be awfully close to updating custom cookbooks:

```
$ aws opsworks create-deployment --command "{\"Name\":\"update_custom_cookbooks\"}"  --stack-id xxxxx --instance-ids xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx #deployment id
```

The documentation doesn't tell me what the format is for the 'execute_recipes' command: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/opsworks/create-deployment.html

After sending it a bunch of guesses and using the gloriously insightful "Invalid value", SerializationException, and ValidationExceptions I have deduced that the following is probably close to what I want:

```
$ aws opsworks create-deployment --command "{\"Name\":\"execute_recipes\", \"Args\":{\"Recipes\":[\"book::recipe\"]}}"  --stack-id xxxxxx --instance-ids xxxxxxxx                                                                                                                                 
A client error (ValidationException) occurred
```

What is the correct JSON schema for getting Opsworks to execute a recipe on a given instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**edit: example fixed, explanation added**

awscli metadata is extremely finnicky and lower/upper case matters. You just have to change the named argument "Recipes" to "recipes" and your command should send a new deployment command to AWS.

```
aws opsworks create-deployment --stack-id xxxx --command '{ "Name": "execute_recipes", "Args": {"recipes": ["book:rec"]}}' --instance-ids xxxx
```

additional discussion: 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=469835&#469835

Comment: the JSON format is case sensitive and does not work as you posted.  However your attempt lead me down another exploratory conversation with the riddle master of an API and I discovered the correct schema by playing with case.  Named arguments are lowercase when passed to the command, but passing the metadata about the command is in Capitals.

Answer (score 0):

Since doing OpsWorks is a bit verbose when using vanilla aws-cli, I came up with a wrapper script that works quite nicely especially when creating cron jobs of OpsWorks recipes. Saves you the tedious task of doing lookups with stack id, opsworks instance id, and all that.

https://github.com/ardeearam/opsworks_local

```
# Run custom recipe to current instance
$ ruby opsworks_local.rb -r mycookbook::jump_high

# Deploy all applications to current instance
$ ruby opsworks_local.rb -c deploy

# Invoke deploy on another server instance
$ ruby opsworks_local.rb -c deploy -i i-7f9811b1

# Update custom cookbook
$ ruby opsworks_local.rb -c update_custom_cookbooks
```